# ElasticSearch NEST Indexing and Searching multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am learning ElasticSearch and using NEST.  I have an object and would like to index multiple fields and then search on combinations of those fields. When I search I am getting results that do not match my search strings. Below is the code to index the data.

```
client.CreateIndex(CurrentIndexName, i => i
    .Settings(s => s
      .NumberOfShards(2)
      .NumberOfReplicas(0)
      .Analysis(analysis => analysis
        .Analyzers(analyzer => analyzer
          .Custom("substring_analyzer", analyzerDescripter => analyzerDescripter
            .Tokenizer("tokenizer")
            .Filters("lowercase")
          )
        )
        .Tokenizers(tk => tk
          .EdgeNGram("tokenizer", tokenizer => tokenizer
            .MaxGram(10)
            .MinGram(2)
            .TokenChars(new List<TokenChar> { TokenChar.Letter, TokenChar.Digit })
          )
        )
      )
    )
    .Mappings(m => m
      .Map<CostCenter>(map => map
        .AutoMap()
        .Properties(ps => ps
          .Text(s => s
            .Name(n => n.CC_Acct_1)
            .Analyzer("substring_analyzer")
          )
          .Text(s => s
            .Name(n => n.CC_Acct_2)
            .Analyzer("substring_analyzer")
          )
          .Text(s => s
            .Name(n => n.CC_Acct_3)
            .Analyzer("substring_analyzer")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Here is my search code.

```
      var searchResult = client.Search<CostCenter>(s => s
    .Size(1000)
    .Query(q => q
      .Match(m => m
        .Field(f => f.CC_Acct_1)
        .Query("0061")
      ) &&
      q.Match(m => m
        .Field(f => f.CC_Acct_2)
        .Query("9061")
      )
    )
  );
```

With this I get results that do not match either string (i.e. CC_Acct_1 = "0056" and CC_Acct_2 = "9056").  If I remove the second match statement everything seems to work.  Is it possible to do what I am trying to accomplish?

UPDATE: Below is a sample of the data that I am indexing.

```
[{
   "Cost_Center": "0056-5711-05910000",
   "CC_Acct_1": "0056",
   "CC_Acct_2": "5711",
   "CC_Acct_3": "5910000",
   },
 {
   "Cost_Center": "0061-9061-05910000",
   "CC_Acct_1": "0061",
   "CC_Acct_2": "9061",
   "CC_Acct_3": "6790000",

 },
 {
   "Cost_Center": "0061-9061-05910000",
   "CC_Acct_1": "0061",
   "CC_Acct_2": "9061",
   "CC_Acct_3": "5910000",
 },
 {
   "Cost_Center": "0056-5711-05910000",
   "CC_Acct_1": "0056",
   "CC_Acct_2": "5711",
   "CC_Acct_3": "6790000",
   },
 {
   "Cost_Center": "0061-5711-05910000",
   "CC_Acct_1": "0061",
   "CC_Acct_2": "5711",
   "CC_Acct_3": "6790000",     
 },
 {
   "Cost_Center": "0056-9061-05910000",
   "CC_Acct_1": "0056",
   "CC_Acct_2": "9061",
   "CC_Acct_3": "5910000",
 },
 {
   "Cost_Center": "0056-9061-05910000",
   "CC_Acct_1": "0056",
   "CC_Acct_2": "9061",
   "CC_Acct_3": "5910000",
   },
 {
   "Cost_Center": "0056-5711-05910000",
   "CC_Acct_1": "0056",
   "CC_Acct_2": "5711",
   "CC_Acct_3": "5910000",
},
 {
   "Cost_Center": "0056-5711-05910000",
   "CC_Acct_1": "0056",
   "CC_Acct_2": "5711",
   "CC_Acct_3": "5910000",
   },
 {
   "Cost_Center": "0056-5711-05910000",
   "CC_Acct_1": "0056",
   "CC_Acct_2": "5711",
   "CC_Acct_3": "5910000",
 }
 ]
```

I have done further research and it looks like the items that match are at the top of my return set (i.e. higher score).  I would like the returned result to only have those that are an exact match.  For example only items where CC_Acct_1 is "0061" and CC_Acct_2 is "9061" or if I had "90" in my second search field items where CC_Acct_2 includes "90".  In this case both items where CC_Acct_2 is "9061" or "1090" would be included.

Comment: It is possible. Would you be able to update your question to index some data, and include what you'd expect to be returned for the given query?

Comment: I'm trying to do a type-ahead so as the user begins typing possible values are shown.

Comment: For type ahead, take a look at the completion suggester: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html. Depending on _how_ you'd like to provide type ahead search, this could suit your needs. If you need to perform more complex analysis, then it may not be suitable, but from the information you've provided, it looks like it may be a good fit

Answer (score 0):

I have made some progress but am not sure this is the best way.  First I changed my query to be the following.

```
var searchResult = client.Search<CostCenter>(s => s
    .Size(1000)
    .Index("test")
    .Query(q => q)
      .MatchPhrase(m => m
        .Field(f => f.CC_Acct_1)
        .Query("0056")
      ) &&
      q.MatchPhrase(m => m
        .Field(f => f.CC_Acct_2)
        .Query("9056")
      ) 
    )
  );
```

This returned the desired results but when I added the query for the third field no results were returned.

```
 var searchResult = client.Search<CostCenter>(s => s
    .Size(1000)
    .Index("test")
    .Query(q => q
      .MatchPhrase(m => m
        .Field(f => f.CC_Acct_1)
        .Query("0056")
      ) &&
      q.MatchPhrase(m => m
        .Field(f => f.CC_Acct_2)
        .Query("9056")
      ) &&
      q.MatchPhrase(m => m
        .Field(f => f.CC_Acct_3)
        .Query("679")
      )
    )
  );
```

I then switched to the following and received the desired results.

```
var searchResult = client.Search<CostCenter>(s => s
    .Size(1000)
    .Index("test")
    .Query(q => q
      .Bool(b => b
        .Must(bs => bs.Term(p => p.CC_Acct_1, "0056"),
          bs => bs.Term(p => p.CC_Acct_2, "9056"),
          bs => bs.Term(p => p.CC_Acct_3, "679")
        )          
      )
    )
  );
```

I can remove any of the lambda functions and get only those items that match what I am looking for.  Let me know if there is a better more efficient way to accomplish this.

Comment: Given the sample data, I don't see how the second and third queries here would return matches - there are no items in the sample collection that contain `"679"` as part of `CC_Acct_3`, which is a requirement to satisfy the query.

Comment: Sorry about that.  The data included above is a partial sample of the data set.  What I originally posted above is the actual code I had and I did not check to see if the last term matched.  I will update it to have matching data.